# How to prevent unwanted animations in UITableViewCell when animating UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I'm animating the height of a UITableView so it aligns with the keyboard's animation like in this article: //http://macoscope.com/blog/working-with-keyboard-on-ios/

However, I am now getting unwanted sideways animations in my cells as they come in.

This used to work when I was adding the contents to the cell view directly because I would override the UITableViewCell method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [super layoutSubviews];
    }];
}
```

But now I'm adding the contents to contentView like you're supposed to.  I need to so the ios8 auto resizing works.  But the solution of laying out subviews without animation no longer seems to apply to content view.

(I just tried not adding things to contentView and the auto sizing still works actually.  I'm still interested in knowing how to properly get contentView contents to not have unwanted animations)